# Use sun-codemodel to generate expression like b().c()

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I'm trying to use [sun-codemodel](http://codemodel.java.net/) to generate source code, checking the API for a long time however no luck.

```
  JBlock body2 = method2.body();

  JInvocation arg = body2.invoke( "a" ).arg( xxx ).invoke( "c" ).arg( xxx );
```

only generate the first part, i.e. a(xxx)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Could elaborate it a bit more, please?

Comment: link added. trying to generate source code like a().b().c()...

Comment: Why doesn't what you have right there do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using

```
      JInvocation invoke = JExpr._this()
                .invoke( "fun" )
                .arg( "arg1" )
                .invoke( "fun2" )
                .arg( "arg2" );
method.body().add(invoke);
```